# SQL LEFT JOIN with date and COUNT

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I got a question about a SQL query that I'm making.

At the moment I got this (I found this with lot of searching on the web):

```
$query = "SELECT
l.login AS login,
u.name AS name,
u.login AS login2,
l.btijd AS tijd,
l.etijd AS etijd
FROM    users AS u
LEFT JOIN     ll AS l
ON (u.login = l.login)
WHERE
code = '$code'
ORDER BY id ASC";
```

But Now I would like to enter data from a third table.
First of all I show the structure of the tables:

```
Users
id---login----name---...
ll
id---code-----login---btijd---etijd-...
```

The table I would like to add:

```
experience
id---login---point----datetime
```

So I would like to add the experience that a user has, but it should be the experience of the last week. This means and example.

```
 User: 1-admin-Test Admin
ll: 00152-561511-admin-2014-09-09 14:15:15
```

experience multiple entries that are used within the weak and multiple that are used more then 1 week ago. So I want to achieve a new variable that per login SUM the points made this week.

Thanks a lot.

PS. I know this is my second question today, but I have serached a lot for both questions and then I found this site so now I ask them both ...

Comment: Instead of searching for the answer, please search more about mysql,sql and joins. You will get a good idea to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following query:-

```
SELECT l.login AS login,
       u.name AS name,
       u.login AS login2,
       l.btijd AS tijd,
       l.etijd AS etijd,
       e.datetime as experience
FROM users AS u
INNER JOIN ll AS l ON (u.login = l.login)
INNER JOIN experience e on (u.login = e.login)
WHERE code = '$code
AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), interval 7 DAYS)
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

This might be helpful to you.